# How to manage max connection, HttpClient, C#?

Tags: c#, windows-services, httpclient, connection-pooling

I'm working on a windows service. Code of windows service is very simple but it has a strange manner!
In windows service I should call a WebApi each 20 seconds and save the result in a SQL Database
 
I'm using `autofac` to creat instance of `HttpClient` at `Program.cs`

```
// HttpClient
builder.Register(ctx =>
{
    var httpClient = new HttpClient
    {
        BaseAddress = new Uri(StaticAssets.WebApiBaseAddress)
    };
    httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
    httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
    return httpClient;
});
```

I never dispose `httpClient` instance manually.
After running the windows service about 8 hours, IIS not work and we can not remote to server anymore, we tested Windows Remote Desktop Connection, VNC(we have VNC on server) ... 
We could remote to server with KVM and stop the windows service and every thing go back.
I could find from [here](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/375383/what-happen-if-we-never-dispose-httpclient-net-c) the problem is because of connection numbers! I'm not sure yet?
Also I found the following:

```
<system.web>
 <processModel maxWorkerThreads="100" maxIoThreads="100" minWorkerThreads="50"/>
 <httpRuntime minFreeThreads="704" minLocalRequestFreeThreads="608"/>
</system.web>

<system.net>
 <connectionManagement>
  <add address="[ProvideIPHere]" maxconnection="96"/>
 </connectionManagement>
</system.net>
```

From https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/821268/contention-poor-performance-and-deadlocks-when-you-make-calls-to-web-s

What is the best practice to manage max connections in `HttpClient` .Net windows service & IIS?

Comment: What is the reason behind not disposing the Client??

Comment: Read https://aspnetmonsters.com/2016/08/2016-08-27-httpclientwrong/

Comment: You should reuse the HttpClient instance, but dispose it when the service is being shutdown. Depending on your configuration of IIS (for instance setting the idle time to be short in AppPool's advanced settings) then you will create a new instance anyway on service restart.

Comment: @MohammadDayyan I didn't knew about the same, thanks for the article.

Comment: @MohammadDayyan The article suggests a fix using a *single* static `HttpClient` instance. I don't really understand what's wrong with this suggested solution?

Comment: @MohammadDayyan Also, are you registering aur `HttpClient` as `Singleton` on Autofac?

Comment: @IpsitGaur, Not yet, I want to find the best practice.

Comment: @Freggar I want to find the best practice, So yousay the solution is OK?

Comment: I guess than in that case, won't your Httpclient be created new instance everytime which is different from the article

Comment: @MohammadDayyan Yes a single `HttpClient` instance is OK see https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/69950/single-instance-of-reusable-httpclient

Comment: I rolled on the floor laughing reading this about the DefaultConnectionLimit property of the HttpClient: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/timomta/controlling-the-number-of-outgoing-connections-from-httpclient-net-core-or-full-framework

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution base on googling:

**1. Define `HttpClient` as SingleTone and don't dispose it manually.**
In `AutoFac` use something like the following:

```
builder.Register(ctx =>
{
    var httpClient = new HttpClient
    {
        BaseAddress = new Uri('https://www.sample.com/')
    };
    httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
    httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
    return httpClient;
}).SingleInstance();
```

In `.Net Core` use the following:

```
services.AddSingleton(provider =>
{
    var httpClient = new HttpClient
    {
        BaseAddress = new Uri('https://www.sample.com/')
    };
    httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
    httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
    return httpClient;
});
```

**2. Add the following in your `config` file**

```
<configuration>
    ....
    <system.web>
     <processModel maxWorkerThreads="100" maxIoThreads="100" minWorkerThreads="50"/>
     <httpRuntime minFreeThreads="704" minLocalRequestFreeThreads="608"/>
    </system.web>

    <system.net>
     <connectionManagement>
      <add address="[ProvideIPHere]" maxconnection="96"/>
     </connectionManagement>
    </system.net>
</configuration>
```